# Do Firebase listeners expire?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

What happens if I have not detached my firebase listeners?

Are they going to listen forever or do they have an expiration date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebase Database listeners stay active until:

1. you remove them in code
2. the app closes the socket that they depend on. In this case the client will try to reestablish a connection when it is active.

Comment: Hi Frank, Is this the same when it comes to using the admin sdk in a nodejs server? I want to use firebase hosting for my new website, and have thought about having an active listener server side, and then delivering the data via different express routes. My thought process is that a user can refresh the page as many times as they want and it would only affect my hosting bandwidth and not my realtime db bandwidth

Comment: In server-side Node.js environments you usually have better control over the socket lifetime than in client-side operating systems. I'd highly recommend doing the math for your logic though, as many developers actually use Firebase precisely as the proxy that you intend to build yourself.